# "cased" where, multiple values for one when

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause, sql-like

Sorry if the title is weird, I can't think of a better one to explain the situation. "WHERE/CASE" part of the query, as of now:

```
where CO_SEGMENT LIKE case (outsideVar)
    when 9999 then '%'
    when 9001 then '9002' --9013, 9014, 9015
    when 9003 then '901[345]'
    when 9004 then '900[56]'
    when 9007 then '900[89]'
    else (outsideVar)
end
```

The idea is I have a list of products, and a list of segments, which groups products. My problem is for some segments cause I need them to list products from "like-conflicted" segments.

From that example above, segment 9001 contains segments 9002 and 9003 - but 9003 is a 'fake segment', he contains segments 9013 thru 9015. I can't put `90[01][2345]` because it would include products from segment `9005` on the list, which don't belong there...

Tips?

PS: I'll only be able to see this on Monday, so happy hew year, folks!

Comment: I am assuming your database is SQL Server.  You should tag it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different ways to use `CASE`, try the other way.

```
WHERE CASE
    WHEN outsideVar = 9999 THEN CO_SEGMENT LIKE '%'
    WHEN outsideVar = 9002 THEN (CO_SEGMENT LIKE '9002' OR CO_SEGMENT LIKE '901[345]')
    WHEN outsideVar = 9003 THEN CO_SEGMENT LIKE '901[345]'
    WHEN outsideVar = 9004 THEN CO_SEGMENT LIKE '900[56]'
    WHEN outsideVar = 9007 THEN CO_SEGMENT LIKE '900[89]'
    ELSE CO_SEGMENT LIKE outsideVar
    END
```

Comment: thanks! I'll try that first thing Monday morning and let you know if it worked - but looks like it does =D

Comment: nope, doesn't work. SQL complains on that first "like" =(

Comment: SQL Fiddle isn't working for me today for some reason.  A couple things that could be tried: changing the first `LIKE` to just be `TRUE`.  I hope not, but we may need to nest CASE statements for example Change `THEN CO_SEGMENT LIKE '901[345]'` to `THEN (CASE WHEN CO_SEGMENT LIKE '901[345]' THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END)`

Comment: thanks, but I ended up changing from `CASE` to boolean =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL pattern using a CTE *map* table instead of a CASE:

```
;with
map as (
  select * from (values
     (9999, '%')
    ,(9001, '9002')
    ,(9003, '901[345]')
    ,(9004, '900[56]')
    ,(9007, '900[89]')
  )t(segment pattern)
),
patterns as (
  select
     data.key
    ,pattern = coalesce(map.pattern,data.outsideVar)
  from dataTable as data
  left join map on map.segment = data.outsideVar)
)
select * 
from dataTable as data
join patterns on data.CO_SEGMENT like patterns.pattern
```

Comment: This is good information, but doesn't answer the problem.  The OP's code works, but segment needs to 9002 includes segment 9003 (which includes 9013, 9014, and 9015).  The original try was `LIKE '90[01][2345]'`, but that gave 9005 (among others) that shouldn't be included.